# Настройка  2 ИП адреса на одном ПК

Tags: ip, маршрутизация, сервер

Такая задача
Есть ПК, роутер trendnet на ПК установлен Windows Server 2003. Так вопрос как на этом ПК настроить два ИП адреса и как заказать 2 ИП у провайдера?

Answer (score 1):

[Тут](http://www.howtogeek.com/51741/how-to-quickly-add-multiple-ip-addresses-to-windows-servers/) написано, как в винде делать множественные ip-адреса, роутер при этом должен работать в режиме бриджа, и у провайдера нужно заказать второй адрес (у каждого провайдера процедура своя, нужно связываться с ним)

Answer (score -1):

Альтернативная конфигурация протокола tcp\ip
И будет 2 ip
(использовал для быстрого переключения между сетками)

> и как заказать 2 ИП у провайдера?

А это уже вопрос к провайдеру.

Answer (score -1):

Провайдер в 99% случаев не дает 2 IP на одну соску ставить. Скорее (и легче) всего затянуть 2 кабеля и поставить вторую сетевуху.

Comment: onlime даёт несколько белых ip искаробки